# Variable does not exist: Interview - when calling Flow.Interview

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, invocable-method

I am creating a method that will call multiple flows. However I am receiving the following error - Variable does not exist: Interview. I have tried using both static and non static to no avail. Below is my code.

```java
public void runFlows(List<Accrue_FlowOrderMap> flowMaps) {
    for(Accrue_FlowOrderMap flow : flowMaps) {
        try {
            Map<String, Object> params = new Map<String, Object>();
            for(Accrue_FlowParams flowParam : flow.params) {
              params.put(flowParam.paramName, flowParam.paramValue);
            }
            Flow.Interview flowToRun = Flow.Interview.createInterview(flow.flowName, params);
            flowToRun.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.debug(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because

```
Flow.Interview flowToRun = Flow.Interview.createInterview(flow.flowName, params);
```

`Flow` is interpreted by the apex compiler to be a reference to the loop variable `flow` !

```
for(Accrue_FlowOrderMap flow : flowMaps)
```

and the loop variable `flow` does not have a property called `Interview`

change your method to be something like this:

```
public void runFlows(List<Accrue_FlowOrderMap> flowMaps) {
    for(Accrue_FlowOrderMap accrueFlow : flowMaps) {
        try {
            Map<String, Object> params = new Map<String, Object>();
            for(Accrue_FlowParams flowParam : accrueFlow.params) {
              params.put(flowParam.paramName, flowParam.paramValue);
            }
            Flow.Interview flowToRun = Flow.Interview.createInterview(accrueFlow.flowName, params);
            flowToRun.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.debug(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! I would have over looked that!!! I was thinking it was case sensitive!!

Comment: apex is not case sensitive; however, Flow input/output variable names are case sensitive